# Web scraping a table in R Fantasy Premier League

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the table from the website: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/statistics?fbclid=IwAR1vShDx0eEefTus-dcxA6anpurcmxz2p4fKHcq1uu9xLj54BYhdpF4pxvc

but it gives 0 elements. Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to try to [solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is best done using the fantasy premier league API. Go here for more info on the API link: https://www.reddit.com/r/FantasyPL/comments/c64rrx/fpl_api_url_has_been_changed/

Using an API in R will require you to do some research, but have a look at the fromJSON() function in the jsonlite package.

This should be enough to get you started, let me know if you have more questions.